# How to store data pairs in django without an extra model?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.4

I want to create an app that stores bills for me. Since I don't have fixed prices for anything there is no need to store my services in an extra model. I just want to store data pairs of "action" and "price" to print them out nicely in a table.

Is there something in django that can help me with that task or should I just put all data pairs together in a textfield and explode it every time i want to use it ?

The number of data pairs per bill is not fixed. Data pairs are used only in one bill, so i don't want an extra table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a plain `TextField` you should look at field types that are better suited for storing structured data: In addition to Acorn's suggestion (django-hstore) a [`JsonField`](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/db/fields/json.py) or a [`PickleField`](https://github.com/shrubberysoft/django-picklefield#readme) might be suitable (and more portable) solutions for your use case.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like the easiest way of doing it :) Are there any pros and cons for using one over the other ? (pickle vs json)

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in Postgres's hstore: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html

https://github.com/jordanm/django-hstore/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that looks like a good way of solving it. But since I'm using mysql I'll go with the JsonField.